# get child group parent view in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

All

i want to change the background of all child group [not individual child in list].

i tried with calling getParent() method `view.getParent()`  but throws error.

**here is my code**

```
        View parentGroup = (View)view.getParent();
        parentGroup.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.CYAN));
```

i want this kind of UI . --> [image: child group background]

**Edit**

**My custom Adapter :**

```
package com.icanstudioz.android.njoyful.adapters;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.icanstudioz.android.njoyful.R;
import com.icanstudioz.android.njoyful.utils.Commons;
import com.icanstudioz.android.pojoclasses.Categories;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableCategoriesListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<Categories>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableCategoriesListAdapter(Context context,
            List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<Categories>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    public int getSubCategoryId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        return _listDataChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition).getId();

    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_list_items, null);
            View parentGroup = (View)view.getParent();
            parentGroup.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.CYAN));
            Commons.applyFont(_context,
                    view.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1),
                    "RobotoSlab-Light.ttf");
            // view.setBackgroundColor(color_arr[position]);
            holder.cat_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
            view.findViewById(R.id.cat_item_check).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Categories dItem = (Categories) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        holder.cat_name.setText(dItem.getCat_name());

        return view;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView cat_name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.order_category_header,
                    null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        Commons.applyFont(_context, lblListHeader, "RobotoSlab-Bold.ttf");
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

hope this helps.

please guide me how can i do this or any other solution?

Comment: I think you need to post a lot more code about what sort of ExpandableListAdapter you are using. There are methods in the adapter where you generate the view for each parent row, view for each child row, and bind them to the data... You are using an adapter, yes?

Comment: yes i used custom adapter for this! let me post my other code.

Comment: just set the background color in getGroupView() of your adapter!

Comment: it only change the background of header. which is already green in my case. i need to set just background of childgroup. as seen in attached screen [the gray color].

Comment: not clear what you mean -- you mean the child views? did you try setting background in getChildView() then?

Comment: yes.. i tried with setting background in getChildView() but it only set particular child background. what i want is to set background of all child under one group. see the image above i want to set background of all this items : "vodka,tequila,whiskey,rum" -> as one background [see the gray bg with top right indicator]. hope i make it clear!

Comment: Did you happen to find answer? I am looking to do the same thing but blocked for now

Comment: unfortunately No!!! if you find , please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67561555/6854117) related to it. Can you please see it?